# How to use CSS selectors in CSS3

Tags: css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="row">
<p> Text </p>
</div>

<div class="row">
<p> Text </p>
<p> Text </p>
</div>
```

I want to apply different styles to all elements that are an only child in the row. I know I can do this for the para as below:

```
.row p:only-child{

//apply your styles 

}
```

**My question is simple:** Is there any shorthand way to apply the `::only-child` styling to all elements in the row parent (e.g. other `div`s), or do I have to mark it up endlessly as:

```
.row .class1:only-child{

//apply your styles 

}

.row class2:only-child{

//apply your styles 

}
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear, please elaborate.

Comment: css is backward compatible...

Answer (score 4):

There are two different levels of this:

```
.row *:only-child
```

Selects all children of `.row` that are the only child, where as

```
.row > *:only:child
```

Selects all the *direct* children of .row that are the only child. Note that you don't actually need the `*` as it will be implied if you just use the `:only-child` selector. Which would make your selector look like `.row > :only-child`.

So, in the following example:

```
<div class="row">
    <p id="p1">Text goes here</p>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <p id="p2"><span id="span1">Text</span></p>
    <p id="p3">More text is here</p>
</div>
```

The first selector will select `#p1` and `#span1`, where as the second will only select `#p1`

Comment: You don't need the * here, `.row > :only-child` will work as well.

Comment: @cimmanon Yes, I'll add that. I was including the `*` for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

you could do

```
.row .class1:only-child, .row.class2:only-child{
    //apply your styles
}
```